# How to get values from variables inside if statement inside for loop in function declaration on python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I try to use value from idCadGen  variable for another function but i cannot acces it. Only when I print it works.
I am beginner on programming and a search a way to solve this issue.

I tried to use global declaration for the variable but i cannot use it.

```
def findIdCad(sheet, nrCad):   
    for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
        row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)
        print "row_value is: " + str(row_value)
        if row_value[6] == int(nrCad):
            idCadGen = str(row_value[0])
            print "IDCADGEN is: " + str(row_value[0])
findIdCad(sheet, nrCad)
print idCadGen
```

Comment: Where did you find this code? If you tell us the source, then we can have some context for this (like what you mean by idCad)

Comment: If you can print it you can use it. What is the error that you are seeing? Also, is the code above the version that works? If so what is the code you are trying to run.

Comment: Try adding at the end of your function a return statement with your variable, like: return idCadGen. Then when you call the function it will evaluate to idCadGen value. Also, you need to initialize idCadGen outside the for-loop in case nrows is 0.